# Asus TUF Ubuntu 18.04.1 elantech mouse freezes frequently

Tags: ubuntu, touchpad, asus

I purchased a ASUS TUF FX504GE laptop and dual booted it with Ubuntu 18.04.1 .After which my elantech touchpad stopped working.I updated my kernel to 4.20.6, after which it does work,but freezes unexpectedly for 3-4 minutes.

After searching about this problem, for some people updating to 4.20 was the solution but still there are peoplefor whom this didn't work.

Some solutions recommended running `xinput`. My results are below:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN1200:00 04F3:3090 Touchpad            id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus Wireless Radio Control               id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD           id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

The output shows id=13 as ELAN1200 touchpad. For the solutions suggested, this was wrongly set to PS/2 etc etc. But for me this value is correct.

I need to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue slightly different hardware.
For me the answer was on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection

Under section two:
In case your Touchpad stops working after a while

The first option: powermanagement did the trick

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Sadly, it didn't work out for me :(

Answer (score 0):

Just extending with my finding, this is for Asus ROG 2016, with ubuntu 16.04.

My findings are, the touchpad enters in a power saving mode. This fixes it for me:

`xinput --set-prop 'Elan Touchpad' 'Synaptics Off' 0`

The exact device can have a different name, use `xinput --list`.